# Compile errors with Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

I try to compile a set of c++ libraries with Xcode (latest) on macOS. I get some errors like

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:334:5: Unknown type name 'locale_t'; did you mean 'locale'?
```

or

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__locale:120:20: Use of undeclared identifier 'LC_COLLATE_MASK'
```

What I do wrong? Missing option? Missing headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google search revealed this link: https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/5108. In short:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
# include <string.h>
# include <xlocale.h>
#endif
```

Comment: Elvir, many thanks for your answer. But finally it was something with double include files. After removed one include path, the compiler worked well. But anyway, thanks for your help.